# Readline dependencie error with stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have this error when I add this dependencie to my project.cabal file.

```
Warning: defaultUserHooks in Setup script is deprecated.
Configuring readline-1.0.3.0...
checking for gcc... /usr/bin/gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether /usr/bin/gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for /usr/bin/gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for GNUreadline.framework... checking for readline... no
checking for tputs in -lncurses... yes
checking for readline in -lreadline... no
checking for rl_readline_version... no
configure: error: readline not found, so this package cannot be built
See `config.log' for more details.
```

what I have to do to solve this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: `readline` is a C library, IIRC, so you have to install it first. You'd also need some sort of `readline-devel` package, if you are running Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Say your are on OSX

```
$ brew install readline
[...]
For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include
```

Now you know where the library got installed you can set some environmental variables that `./configure` will pick up

```
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib \
CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/readline/include \
stack install readline --extra-include-dirs=/usr/local/opt/readline/include --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/local/opt/readline/lib
```